# push an 'unchecked out' branch

Tags: git

I want to push a branch (not the current) without having to check it out first, how can I achieve that ?

this is how I'd do:

```
#currently in master
git checkout feature
git push origin feature
git checkout master
```

but checking out feature can cause conflicts, can't I just push another branch than the current one ?

Comment: Possibly related with a different solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51342767/push-a-git-branch-to-remote-without-checking-the-branch-out

Comment: Note there is a risk associated with this practice: If you have [push hooks](https://githooks.com/), they will run on your current branch instead of the branch you want to push.

Answer (score 230, accepted):

Simply:

```
git push origin feature:feature
```

Or shorter:

```
git push origin feature
```

Comment: Is it necessary to write `feature:feature` or could you just write `git push origin feature` ?

Comment: @Glemi  No it's optional; checkout the refspec bit in [the manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push).

Comment: It doesnt work for me,, saying error: src refspec dev does not match any // error: failed to push some refs

Comment: If you have git hooks (pre-push) setup, which branch runs the git hooks: the branch you're on, or the branch you're pushing? I believe its the former. Example: if I'm on feature branch but want to push master to origin without having to checkout master first. I believe git hooks will run for feature and not for master.

Comment: @nodebase It probably depends how you write the hook script;  I am no expert on git hooks but I found an [example](https://gist.github.com/pixelhandler/5718585) that stops force pushes to `master`.