# Push a Git branch to remote without checking the branch out

Tags: git, git-checkout

Is there a way to push a branch to a Git remote without checking that branch out first?

Say I am on the master branch, and there is a release branch that I want to push to the remote, is there a way to push the release branch to the Git remote without having to check it out first?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18031946/what-does-set-upstream-do

Comment: @jmargolisvt did you read the question? The answer in that link says "sets the default remote branch for the current local branch." The point of this question is push a branch to a remote, if you haven't currently checked that branch out

Comment: @AlexanderMills looks like at least two other people agree that setting upstream might be the answer the OP is looking for.  If you think you have a better reading of the question, I encourage you to post your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> git push -u origin new_branch_name

Answer (score 0):

This question looks to me like a duplicate of [push an 'unchecked out' branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583231/push-an-unchecked-out-branch?noredirect=1&lq=1). (Hooray for the "related" section.)

If the feature branch has the same name in both the local repository and in `origin`, you can use the following shorthand:

```
git push origin <feature_branch_name>
```

[See this example in the manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt-codegitpushoriginmastercode). Otherwise specify both names with

```
git push origin <local_branch_name>:<remote_branch_name>
```